# How to make vim output the result from make continuously

Tags: vim, make

When you run the `:make` command in Vim, the output will be displayed page by page as if it 
was piped to `more`. I want to disable this. It is irritating to keep pressing the space bar repeatedly especially if the output is very large.
*How do I do this?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't observe this behavior, but the corresponding Vim option is:

```
:set nomore
```

> When on, listings pause when the whole screen is filled.  You will get
>   the |more-prompt|.  When this option is off there are no pauses, the
>   listing continues until finished.

Also, check your `'makeprg'` and ensure that it doesn't contain a pager.

Comment: I retract my comment(it suppresses the output), yours rules. Alas! the prompts are nomore. ;)